# Regex Pattern matching for unique ids

Tags: regex, string, shell, scripting, pattern-matching

I am writing a shell script that searches a text file for a pattern.

The pattern is: uid-  and then an alphanumeric string containing only lower case letters and numbers. For example: uid-12ab34de

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(grep -R "^uid-[a-z][0-9]" "./text.txt")
echo "$value"
```

I have several attempts at this now and have come here as a last resort. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(grep -R "^uid-[a-z0-9]+$" "./text.txt")
echo "$value"
```

Your regexp chose a single lowercase letter followed by a single digit. Moreover, it would have accepted strings that have a valid uid as a prefix only (i.e. ending in illegal/unsupported characters). The latter may have been intentional, if so drop the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value=$(grep -ER "^uid-[a-z0-9]+" "./text.txt")
```

`-E` for using ERE (Extended Regular Expression)

You can do this too (for GNU grep) in BRE (Basic Regular Expression) mode:

```
value=$(grep -R "^uid-[a-z0-9]\+" "./text.txt")
```

Or:

```
value=$(grep -R "^uid-[a-z0-9]\{1,\}" "./text.txt")
```

If you want portability with BRE, then:

```
value=$(grep -R "^uid-[a-z0-9]*" "./text.txt")
```

But this will match even the id portion of the uid is empty (like `uid-`)

A little explanation:

`+`, `\+` `\{1,\}` matches for at least one or more occurrences of the precedent regex.

`*` matches zero or more occurrences of the precedent regex.